# Cant get jsp file to work correctly, wont do what is scripted

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am trying to make a simple "multi search engine" page and I am already having issues with some of my code. So far I've only coded in google, however it doesn't work, and I am wondering why, as all the code seems to be correct. It wont redirect at all, just gives me a blank page. I am running the jsp file on a tomcat server (port 8080). Hopefully someone can find what I did wrong, thanks.

Here is the HTML for the main page:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Multi Search Engine Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h1>Search test</h3>
        </center>
        <br>
        <br>
        <center>
            <form action="192.168.2.127:8080/main/search.jsp" method="POST">
                <input type="text" id="search" name="Search" />
                <select name="site">
                    <option value="google">Google</option>
                    <option value="yahoo">Yahoo</option>
                    <option value="bing">Bing</option>
                    <option value="youtube">Youtube</option>
                    <option value="reddit">Reddit</option>
                    <option value="amazon">Amazon</option>
                    <option value="ebay">Ebay</option>
                </select> 
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </form>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the code for the jsp file:

```
<% 
String search=(String)request.getAttribute("search");
String site=(String)request.getAttribute("site");
%>
<script>
    if(site == "google")
    {
        window.open("https://google.com/search?q="+<%= search %>, "_blank");
    }
    else
    {
        window.open("http://192.168.2.127/error.html");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jsp code seems to have some mistakes.

For example, the `if(site == "google")` compares the undefined JavaScript variable `site` with the string "google". I think you want `if("<%= site %>" == "google")`, meaning that you will print the jsp variable `site` inside quotes, thus the resulted JavaScript code will be a string comparison with a string.

There is a similar mistake on `window.open("https://google.com/search?q="+<%= search %>, "_blank");`. For example, if you send the query `hello world`, your jsp will produce the code `window.open("https://google.com/search?q="+hello world, "_blank");` which is invalid JavaScript code. Thus, you need to wrap the jsp `search` variable in quotes, like that `window.open("https://google.com/search?q=" + "<%= search %>", "_blank");` or even better also encode the string since it will be used on a URL `window.open("https://google.com/search?q="+encodeURIComponent("<%= search %>"), "_blank");`

With all that being said, there is no point using a back-end just to throw the work back to the JavaScript. Right now your back-end is only echoing the form data back to the JavaScript.

Also, raw printing string variables and passing them to the JavaScript allows Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) if not done right (safe printing). For example in your case, an attacker may search for `" + alert('xss') + "` and your jsp will print the code `window.open("https://google.com/search?q="+encodeURIComponent("" + alert('xss') + ""), "_blank");` which will be eventually be executed at the client.

Some more things to consider, on your form action, always define the URL with the protocol, unless it is a relative path (to avoid confusion and future bugs). So, do not use `<form action="192.168.2.127:8080/main/search.jsp" method="POST">` use `<form action="http://192.168.2.127:8080/main/search.jsp" method="POST">`.

And please, don't use `center`, it is 2019 :P.